# Prevent friend function from accessing private member of a class

Tags: c++, oop, private, friend, functor

How can we prevent friend function from accessing private member of a class. Can we do this at all?

This question was asked in an interview and he was confident that it can be done, he gave hint about functor / function object. So far I can't think of anything. I am excited about the answer, if any.

Comment: Don't make the function a `friend` of the class?

Comment: [pimpl](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl)? The closest thing i can imagine.

Comment: I don't understand such code-golfy questions in an interviews. What information such questions provide about the interviewee, that will be useful in the role they are applying for? The sole purpose of `friend` is to allow it to access the `private` members.

Comment: I guess they want to check OOP knowledge. There might be some good application as well but I will never encourage any such thing in my codebase.

Comment: Only answer I could give to such an interview question: "Sorry, I don't think I would be a good fit for this company".

Comment: @felix How does the pimpl idiom help about that, unless anonymous namespace stuff is introduced?

Comment: I have a serious doubt this can be done. It's easier to gain access to a private member (yes, it can be done, see [this](http://bloglitb.blogspot.ca/2011/12/access-to-private-members-safer.html)) rather to block access once it's given.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It doesn't help, but might be the answer which the interviewer is expecting, even if it isn't the answer to the question which he is actually asking. (A guy was once asked about how to prevent user code from memcpy a singleton...)

Answer (score 2):

> How can we prevent friend function from accessing private member of a class. Can we do this at all?

No, you cannot.

As soon something is declared as `friend` of your class the doors to access any `private` members are opened.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of Encapsulation is to bundle data and methods (that work on the data) together and restrict access of private data members outside the class. In C++, a friend function or friend class can also access private data members.